# Get row index of clicked button properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, onclick, row

I've tried several ways to get the row index of a clicked button inside a table.

The table:

```php
while ($info = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
    echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>{$info['name']}</th>";
        echo "<th>{$info['pass']}</th>";
        echo "<th><a href='http://{$info['link']}'>{$info['link']}</a></th>";
        echo "<th><div class='delbuttons'><button class='btn btn-info' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal' id='{$info['id']}'>Delete</button></div></th>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
?>
```

These are the ways that I've tried:

```lang-js
$(document).on('click', '.delbuttons button', function(event) {
    alert($(this).index());
}
```

but it always returns **-1**.

```
$(document).on('click','.delbuttons button', function(event) {
    alert(this.rowIndex);
}
```

This returns **undefined**.

Comment: Welcome back :-). -- Why `<th>` rather than `<td>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is in this line:

```
alert($(this).index());
```

According to the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/index/):

> .index(): Search for a given element from among the matched elements.

Because your button is the unique element contained in the div the correspondig result will be always 0.

In order to get the row index, instead, it is sufficient to get the index of the closest tr:

```
$(this).closest('tr').index()
```

In your second approach you try to get the [rowIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableRowElement/rowIndex) of the clicked button. But this attribute is related only to a table row element. Hence, in this case you will get **undefined**.

```js
$(document).on('click','.delbuttons button', function(event) {
    console.log($(this).closest('tr').index());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>name1</td>
        <td>pass1</td>
        <td><a href="http://xxx">xxx</a></td>
        <td>
            <div class="delbuttons">
                <button class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="id1"> Delete</button>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>name2</td>
        <td>pass2</td>
        <td><a href="http://xxx">xxx</a></td>
        <td>
            <div class="delbuttons">
                <button class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="id2"> Delete</button>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>name3</td>
        <td>pass3</td>
        <td><a href="http://xxx">xxx</a></td>
        <td>
            <div class="delbuttons">
                <button class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="id3"> Delete</button>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```js
$(document).on('click','.delbuttons button', function() {
    console.log($(this).closest('tr').get(0).rowIndex);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table><tr>

             <th>A</th>
             <th>B</th>
             <th>C</th>
             <th><div class='delbuttons'><button  class='btn btn-info' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'> Delete </button> </div> </th> </tr>
             <tr>

             <th>A</th>
             <th>B</th>
             <th>C</th>
             <th><div class='delbuttons'><button  class='btn btn-info' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'> Delete </button> </div> </th> </tr>
             </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

try at this way:

```
$(document).on('click','.delbuttons button', function() {
     console.log($(this).closest("tr").index(););
});
```

or try to

```
$(document).on('click','.delbuttons button', function() {
     console.log($(this).parent().index(););
});
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19356880)

Comment: you do not let it grow to me @ponury-kostek, if I do not give my solutions I will never improve my reputation

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest solution i found:

```
event.target.closest('tr').rowIndex
```

1. event.target gets the current button that fired the event and executing this function.
2. closest('tr') gets the row that contains the current button.
3. rowIndex gets the index of te row in its table.